# Setting element color style in Razor using Ternary ? operator

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have an HTML element which repeats itself throughout the foreach loop in my razor cshtml document like following:

```
//@foreach(var item in Collection) ...  then goes this element...

 <div title="Find Item" value="@item.ID" class="btn btn-default btnItem"><i class="fa fa-bullseye" style="@(item.IsItemAvailable? "color:green" : "color:red")"></i></div>
```

Please note the following part:

```
style="@(item.IsItemAvailable? "color:green" : "color:red")"
```

I'm trying to set the color of the element based on the ViewModel Property Called IsItemAvailable, and if the item is available I will set the element color to green, otherwise set it to red...

I assume that the first thing that goes after the ? operator is when the statement is true , thus it would mean item is indeed available and it's color should be set to green??

But for some reason button color is always set to red?? What am I doing wrong here guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Html.Raw` method to render the css.

```
<div title="Find Item" value="@item.ID" class="btn btn-default btnItem">
    <i class="fa fa-bullseye" 
     style="@(item.IsItemAvailable? Html.Raw("color:green") : Html.Raw("color:red"))"></i>
</div>
```